# Python Selenium Unable to get Browser even though browser is open

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import datetime

site = 'URL'
browser = webdriver.Ie()
browser.implicitly_wait(1)
browser.get(site)
#time.sleep(1)

 browser.get_screenshot_as_file('screen_shot_test'
+str(datetime.datetime.now())+'.png')
browser.close()
```

I am trying to save a screenshot of my webpage but when I try to screenshot it I get the error saying "Unable to get Browser" even though the webpage I am trying to reach is open and ready to be screenshotted. I am new to selenium and very confused, all help is appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code on my machine using the Chrome driver(don't have IE) and it works perfectly. Although this isn't a solution to your code(was going to just comment but don't have enough reps) but try changing the web browser. It may be a problem with the current version of IE on your machine(try updating?)